# Hall's marriage theorem: sufficiency proof by contraposition

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, alternative-proof, matching-theory

**EDIT**: New proof (sorry for bumping, but would be nice to have this answered).

I have an alternative proof of Hall's marriage theorem, and would like to know whether it is correct? If yes, how can it be improved? If not, why?

The proof goes by proving the sufficiency of the condition using contraposition.

Let $S_1,\ldots,S_n \subseteq X, |X|=n,$ be a collection of nonempty subsets, and suppose that there aren't distinct $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in X$, such that $x_i\in S_i, i=1,\ldots,n$. Then, there is an $I\subset \{1,\ldots,n\}$, such that $|I| > |\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i|$.

*Proof*:
Suppose that there are at most $x_1,\ldots,x_m\in X, m < n$, distinct elements, such that $x_i \in S_i, i=1,\ldots,m$ without loss of generality. We clearly have $|I| \leq |\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i|$ for all $I\subseteq M$ where $M=\{1,\ldots, m\}$.

Define $A = \{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}, B= X\setminus A$ and $X_{I} = \bigcup_{i\in I} S_i$.
Now pick any $S_k, m < k \leq n$, and note that $S_k\subseteq A$, since otherwise there would be $m+1$ distinct pairs. Now define the sequence of intervals $\{I_j\subseteq M\}$, where
$$
I_1 = \{i\in M:S_k\cap S_i\neq \emptyset~\text{and}~S_i\cap B = \emptyset\},
$$
and $$I_j = \{i\in M:S_i\cap X_{I_{j-1}}\neq \emptyset~\text{and}~S_i\cap B = \emptyset\}, j > 1.$$

Then $X_{I_j}\cap B = \emptyset$ and $S_k\subseteq X_{I_1}\subseteq\cdots\subseteq X_{I_j}$ for all $j\geq 1$ by construction. Furthermore, since for each $x\in X_{I_j}$ there is at least one $S_i, i \in M,$ such that $x\in S_i$ by assumption, it follows that
$$
\left|X_{I_j}\right|\leq \left|I_{j+1}\right| \leq\left|X_{I_{j+1}}\right|\leq m
$$
for all $j\geq 1$. Thus, it follows that there is a $p\geq 1$, such that $\left|X_{I_p}\right|=\left|I_p\right|$.

Finally since $k\notin M$, $$|I_p \cup \{k\}| = |I_p|+1 > |I_p| = |X_{I_p}| = |S_k \cup X_{I_p}|.$$

Comment: Why are we assuming that the $S_i$ form a cover of $X$Can we have $S_1=S_2….=x \in X$? Maybe I’m missing an assumption or a misunderstanding…

Comment: @Bey Good question. First notice that the $S_i$'s are nonempty. Second, if we have an $x\in X$ not covered by the $S_i$'s, then we can remove that element from $X$ and work with that.

We can have $S_1 = S_2 =... = \{x\}$, then we have one unique pair among these (note that we can have more, if not all $S_i = \{x\}$.

Comment: Ah, ok -- so implicitly we assume that $X$ is the minimal set (i.e., covered). I ask because you make this statement.   "Thus, we must have $x_j \in S_i$ for some $1\leq i \leq m$, for all $m < j \leq n$, and by extension, $|\bigcup_{i=1}^mS_i| = n$.? WHich only makes sense if $S_i$ are a cover.